# Maxima: How to avoid negative symbol in the front of an expression

Tags: math, expression, maxima

Here is my test code:

```
kill(all)$
assume(beta>0 and gamma>0)$
simpsum:true$
assume(beta<1 and gamma<=1)$
f2:1-sum((1-beta)^l*(1-gamma)^(l-1)*gamma,l,1,inf),ratsimp;
```

The output is:

[image]

There is actually a negative sign in the front of the equation. The equation is:

-beta/((beta-1)*gamma-beta)

But you often neglect the negative sign as it is too close to the fraction. I do not like a equation with a negative sign in the beginning either.

Is there anyway in Maxima that can avoid the negative sign in the front of an equation? I want to transform the example equation to:

[image]

**Update - the error when using :lisp**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know a way to get Maxima to bring the minus sign into the fraction. But maybe this will help: you can tell wxMaxima to display the minus sign differently by changing its display property. Try this:

```
:lisp (setf (get 'mminus 'wxxmlsym) '("<v>- </v>"))
```

By default, the string is "-", i.e., with no trailing space. Of course, you can make the string anything you like.

Comment: This line ends up with errors in wxMaxima: incorrect syntax: 1) ' is not an infix operator, 2) incorrect syntax: Too many )'s

Comment: @Leo Did you enter the `:lisp` at the start?

Comment: I have updated the error figure in the question. Thanks for further help.

Comment: @Leo You need to put `:lisp` in a cell by itself.

Comment: It works. Thanks. The only annoying bit is that I have to additionally execute the cell of :lisp. I normally write all my code in one cell. Then execute it only once. :)

Comment: @Leo You can put any Lisp stuff into a file named `maxima-init.lisp` and put it somewhere that Maxima can find it (e.g., in the directory named by `maxima_userdir`), and it will be loaded automatically when Maxima starts up. You can see the value of `maxima_userdir` by just entering `maxima_userdir;` in a wxMaxima cell. Note that when you put Lisp code into `maxima-init.lisp`, you put just the Lisp expression `(setf ...)` and omit the `:lisp` which is needed only to tell Maxima that the following stuff is Lisp.

Comment: This is very interesting! Where can I find documentation or any information about it? For a concrete example: How can I produce a list of defined symbols, besides 'mminus?