# wxMaxima: How to add space to minus sign permanently

Tags: math, lisp, maxima

As reported in a comment to an answer to [Maxima: How to avoid negative symbol in the front of an expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26503789/maxima-how-to-avoid-negative-symbol-in-the-front-of-an-expression), adding the line `(setf (get 'mminus 'wxxmlsym) '("<v>- </v>"))` to the file `maxima-init.lisp` should make this be executed at startup of each maxima session.

I did as advised and created this file in my maxima_userdir `$HOME/.maxima` as reported by `maxima_userdir;`.  I am sure that it is read, since I get error messages if I put junk in the file.  Nevertheless I see no effect in wxMaxima 14.12.1.

What can be wrong?  Does the setting get overwritten after the file was read?

Comment: I can't get it to work, either (with the same version of wxMaxima on Windows 7). It might be better to ask on http://news.gmane.org/gmane.comp.mathematics.maxima.general - they are very good about responding to and fixing bugs in maxima.

Comment: Thanks for the hint.  Here it is: http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.mathematics.maxima.general/48114